# bottom-tab-navigator gets hidden when I navigate to another screen using drawer

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I'm using the bottom tab and drawer navigator in my react-native project using expo. I'm using react-navigation v5 in my project. I'm not sure why but when I navigate to another screen using drawer, I tend to lose bottom tab bar on that page. Can anyone help me to keep it constant on every page?

https://snack.expo.io/rkC_VVFE8

Comment: You have nested Tabs inside Drawer. Try nesting Drawer inside Tabs.

Comment: If I nest drawer inside the tab, then on the switching to the second tab I wouldn't be able to use the  drawer.

Comment: I think you need to wrap a HOC with Tabs for each Drawer Item.

Comment: Ahwin can You elaborate more how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I will tell you the most simplest way to use both tab navigation and drawer. I just figured it out couple of days back.

```js
const AppDrawer = () => {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator>
      <Drawer.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={BottomTabNavigation}
        options={{
          headerShown: false,
        }}
        initialParams={{ screenName: 'Dashboard' }} // Set route params here for Dashboard screen
      />
     
      <Drawer.Screen
        name="Setting"
        component={BottomTabNavigation}
        options={{
          headerShown: false,
        }}
        initialParams={{ screenName: 'Settings' }} // Set route params here for Settings screen
      />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
};

export default AppDrawer;
```

So, as you can see I'm passing my bottom tab navigation component in all the drawer screen so it won't get hide. Make sure to add to initialParams property on drawer screens because we will use it in tab navigation to renders tab conditionally.

> Note: Make sure that the name you are passing to screen and to
> initialParams should be different.

```js
const BottomTabNavigation = ({route }) => {

    const { screenName } = route.params

    return (
        <Tab.Navigator
            initialRouteName={screenName}
        >

            <Tab.Screen
                options={{ headerShown: false, tabBarShowLabel: false }}
                name="Dashboard"
            >
                {() => <DashboardScreen user={user} setCount={setCount} count={count} />}
            </Tab.Screen>


            <Tab.Screen
                options={{ headerShown: false, tabBarShowLabel: false }}
                name="Settings"
            >
                {() => <SettingsScreen user={user} />}
            </Tab.Screen>
        </Tab.Navigator>
    );
};

export default BottomTabNavigation
```

Here's my tab navigation structure. I'm getting the screenName that we passed in the drawer navigation inside. And using initial route name to make the exact tab active that we will press through drawer navigation.

> Note: if you get any trouble getting route prop inside tab navigation
> you can use the below code.

```js
import { useRoute } from '@react-navigation/native';

const route  = useRoute()
const {screenName} = route.params
```

I hope this answer will help you if it does let me know. This is my first post ever on stack overflow.Have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

You nested Drawer (MyDrawer) in Tab.Screen and nested Tab.Navigator in NavigationContainer.

example code: [Gist](https://gist.github.com/kadiryaka/1f8729bb0dcd61eb2ca4721960e9f6ef)

solution to your code:

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
        <Tab.Navigator>
          <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={MyDrawer} />
          <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
        </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Comment: with the above code, i would probably lose the drawer if i navigate to the Settings screen

Comment: Yes. you are right. Unfortunately, NavigationContainer component contains a single container. when I added multi Navigator, error say:   **Another navigator is already registered for this container. You likely have multiple navigators under a single "NavigationContainer" or "Screen". Make sure each navigator is under a separate "Screen" container.**